# Trying to find a better way to combine results of computations by different threads (OpenMP)

Tags: c++, openmp

The task is to find the matrix. There are two independent parts of calculation that can be done by different threads at the same time. So I've devided all the work between to groups of four threads. When all the work is done by each group of threads I need to combine the result of calculations. For this purpose I've created another parallel region to ensure that all the preparatory work is done before I start calculating the final result.

The result is correct and it works properly but there is an overhead as I've created another parallel region only to perform one simple task. Can I avoid creating adittional parallel region and provide propper execution of the code at the same time?

```
            omp_set_nested(1);
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
            {
                if (omp_get_thread_num() == 0) {
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
                    {
                        transposeMatrix(A, TrA);
                        multiplyMatrix(TrA, B, R1);
                        subtractMatrix(D, R1, R2);
                    }
                } else {
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
                    {
                        reverseMatrix(C, eC, rC);
                    }
                }
            }

    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
            {
                addUpMatrices(rC, R2, R3);
            }
```

Comment: That's right, all OpenMP worksharing directives are inside the functions.

Comment: Without seeing inside the *Matrix functions it's impossible to understand what's going on here. In general nested parallelism is a bad idea, and you should reach for OpenMP tasks instead, also forcing thread counts is a bad idea...